# Ubuntu SDK : ubuntu emulator causes freeze Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-sdk

i have problem with in ubuntu sdk, first, when i add the emulator, it always stop downloading at 90% of the process, and i repeat that process again twice, but in last attempt, the process finish so quickly and the emulator is added, but something wrong happen.

when i start up emulator it takes at least 2 minutes and then the entire system freeze(i try to re-run it, but it still cause the entire system freeze), and the black screen with some text appears(and it still so for hours), so i have to force my laptop shutdown.

i create ubuntu emulator with this setting :

1. Architecture : ARM64
2. Channel : Devel

is anything wrong with my system or the step when i adding ubuntu emulator??

i have ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 Bit). thank you in advance :)

Comment: The best way to do development is to switch to the current short term release, or latest alpha/beta such as 15.10. 14.04 is more for maintaining a stable desktop system, rather than a bleeding edge development platform.